# How to disable the Etag in npm express at configuration level?

Tags: express, npm, etag

I am new to nodejs and npm. I have been task to disable Etag generation in the configuration level of npm express. I am finding the answer as
`app.set('etag', false); // turn off` and similar to this in online.

Disabling in the sense not in the application code, I have to disable in the express configuration of npm. Like for every request I need to get response only from server as `application/json` and the status should only be `200`. Please help to find a solution.

sample code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 9000

app.get('/proj/v1/test', (req, res) => {
// app.set('etag', false);
res.status(200).json({status: "OK"});
}
)
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: The way you configure Express is via application code. There is no external configuration.

Comment: @robertklep: Thank you for your response. I said the same to my lead but he says adding "app.set('etag', 'false');" in the code is wrong. He told me to stop generating the Etag in configuration level of express. Like no Etag generation should happen. By that way HTTP should look to the server every-time for response.

Comment: Perhaps he meant that adding `app.set('etag', false)` at the location of the code that you put it (inside a request handler) is wrong? Because typically, it's done at a higher level (in your example code, _before_ `app.get(...)`).

Comment: Actually his concept is he doesn't want me to use `app.set('etag', false)` in the code at all. Instead he is telling me to do configuration changes of `experess/npm`. Is there anything I have to change in **package-lock.json** file's "etag and express" keys?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like is any way to configure Express externally (from outside the application). Besides, changing code of modules directly is a maintainance nightmare. I don't see why he doesn't want to use the correct (documented) way of disabling etags.

Comment: Can you please share me any document related to this? so that I can convince him by showing that.

Comment: I can only refer to the [official documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) (look for the `etag` setting).

Answer (score 0):

Robert thanks for your help. My Lead was mentioning about middleware concept. The actual response he needed is to verify the every request. I got a fix with the below code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 9000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  app.disable('etag');
  console.log('Etag removed');
next();
})

app.get('/proj/v1/test', (req, res) => {
res.status(200).json({status: "OK"});
}
)

app.get('/proj/v1/test2', (req, res) => {
res.status(200).json({version: "1"});
}
)
console.log('Server started');
app.listen(port);
```